# How can I access multiple alt attribute values from several images?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, object

I need to retrieve alt attribute value from multiple images and print them below image. I can only get one of them with the below attempt.

**JavaScript:**

```
let imgName = document.getElementById(project)
.getElementsByTagName("img")[0].alt

document.getElementById(project)
.getElementsByClassName("img-name")[0].innerText = imgName;
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="pagination"></div>

<div class="imgslide noselect">
    <div class="prev" onclick="plusDivs('project1', -1)"></div>
    <div class="next" onclick="plusDivs('project1', 1)"></div>
    <img class="slides" alt="image1"src="img/project-1/Scan-4.jpg">
    <img class="slides" alt="image2"src="img/project-1/Scan-8.jpg">
    <img class="slides" alt="image3"src="img/project-1/Scan-24.jpg">
    <img class="slides" alt="image4"src="img/project-1/Scan-35.jpg">
    <img class="slides" alt="image5"src="img/project-1/Scan-39.jpg">
    <img class="slides" alt="image6"src="img/project-1/Scan-40.jpg">
</div>
<div class="img-name"></div>
```

Comment: You loop over the collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loop through the children and create an array or frankly do whatever you want.

```js
var elements = document.querySelector('.imgslide').children;

let altArray = [];
for(let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if(elements[i].src !== undefined) {
        altArray.push(elements[i].alt);
    }
}

console.log(altArray);
```

```html
<div class="imgslide noselect">
  <div class="prev" onclick="plusDivs('project1', -1)"></div>
  <div class="next" onclick="plusDivs('project1', 1)"></div>
  <img class="slides" alt="image1"src="img/project-1/Scan-4.jpg">
  <img class="slides" alt="image2"src="img/project-1/Scan-8.jpg">
  <img class="slides" alt="image3"src="img/project-1/Scan-24.jpg">
  <img class="slides" alt="image4"src="img/project-1/Scan-35.jpg">
  <img class="slides" alt="image5"src="img/project-1/Scan-39.jpg">
  <img class="slides" alt="image6"src="img/project-1/Scan-40.jpg">
</div>
<div class="img-name"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create an array of all image elements and map the `alt` attributes into the array like so:

```js
 

const altArray = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("slides")).map(e => e.alt);
console.log(altArray);
```

```html
 

<div class="imgslide noselect">
            <div class="prev" onclick="plusDivs('project1', -1)"></div>
            <div class="next" onclick="plusDivs('project1', 1)"></div>
            <img class="slides" alt="image1"src="img/project-1/Scan-4.jpg">
            <img class="slides" alt="image2"src="img/project-1/Scan-8.jpg">
            <img class="slides" alt="image3"src="img/project-1/Scan-24.jpg">
            <img class="slides" alt="image4"src="img/project-1/Scan-35.jpg">
            <img class="slides" alt="image5"src="img/project-1/Scan-39.jpg">
            <img class="slides" alt="image6"src="img/project-1/Scan-40.jpg">
        </div>
        <div class="img-name"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this by first querying all `.slides` in your document and then mapping each slide element's `alt` attribute to aquire all alt tags of your slides.

In the snippet below, `Array.from` is used to transform the result of `document.querySelectorAll(".slides")` into an `Array` type - this allows us to use the `Array#map` method to map each `slide` elements `alt` attribute into a temporary array.

The final step `.join()` creates a comma separated from the string array that results from the prior `.map()`:

```js
var innerText = 
// Select all slides and construct array from NodeList
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".slides")) 
// Map each alt attribute to temporary array
.map(image => image.getAttribute("alt")) 
// Construct a comma separated of each alt text
.join() 

document.querySelector(".img-name").innerText = innerText;
```

```html
<div class="imgslide noselect">
  <div class="prev" onclick="plusDivs('project1', -1)"></div>
  <div class="next" onclick="plusDivs('project1', 1)"></div>
  <img class="slides" alt="image1" src="img/project-1/Scan-4.jpg">
  <img class="slides" alt="image2" src="img/project-1/Scan-8.jpg">
  <img class="slides" alt="image3" src="img/project-1/Scan-24.jpg">
  <img class="slides" alt="image4" src="img/project-1/Scan-35.jpg">
  <img class="slides" alt="image5" src="img/project-1/Scan-39.jpg">
  <img class="slides" alt="image6" src="img/project-1/Scan-40.jpg">
</div>
<div class="img-name"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a cool kid would do I'd do this manner @tomas

```
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img')

imgs.map(img => {
   // enter code here
   console.log(img.getAttribute('alt'))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick and elegant solution would be this:

```js
imgnames.textContent = [...document.querySelectorAll('.slides')].map(i=>i.alt).join(' ');
```

```css
#imgnames {
  border: 3px dotted #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgslide noselect">
  <div class="prev" onclick="plusDivs('project1', -1)"></div>
  <div class="next" onclick="plusDivs('project1', 1)"></div>
  <img class="slides" alt="image1" src="img/project-1/Scan-4.jpg">
  <img class="slides" alt="image2" src="img/project-1/Scan-8.jpg">
  <img class="slides" alt="image3" src="img/project-1/Scan-24.jpg">
  <img class="slides" alt="image4" src="img/project-1/Scan-35.jpg">
  <img class="slides" alt="image5" src="img/project-1/Scan-39.jpg">
  <img class="slides" alt="image6" src="img/project-1/Scan-40.jpg">
</div>
<div class="img-name" id="imgnames"></div>
```

1. `imgnames` is the `id` of the `div` for outputting the image names. Since it has an `id` it is automatically available as a global variable.
2. To set the text of that div, assign it to  the `textContent` property of that element.
3. `document.querySelectorAll('.slides')` gets you a `NodeList` containing reference of all the image elements.
4. `[...document.querySelectorAll('.slides')]` creates an array from that `NodeList`...
5. ... which then allows you to use `Array.prototype.map()` to create another array from it which contains only the contents of each image's `alt` attribute.
6. Finally, join that array using `Array.prototype.join(' ')` so it becomes a String and thus, assignable to `imgnames.textContent`.